# ldply with subset does not see local variable

Tags: r

i have a list of team names (teamNames) and a list of data frames (weekSummaries)

i want to get a list of team summaries by week:

```
teamSummaries <- llply(teamNames,getTeamSubset)

getTeamSubset = function(teamName){
  temp=ldply(weekSummaries,subset,team_name==teamName)
}
```

however, when i run this i get an error

```
>Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'teamName' not found
```

but when i run the command

```
>ldply(weekSummaries,subset,team_name=="Denver Broncos")
```

i get a data frame with the information i need for one team... can somebody point out what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset.

Comment: thanks @mnel. from looking at those links, it looks like subset works within the scope of the data_frame it is passed. i couldn't seem to sort out how to fix it with eval. i'm posting an alternate solution that uses a custom function, thus avoiding subset altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is not to use the subset function, and instead to use a custom function, passing it the data frame, then subsetting using bracket notation. such as this:

```
teamSummaries <- llply(teamNames,getTeamSubset)

getTeamSubset = function(teamName){
  temp=ldply(weekSummaries,function(week){
    week[week$team_name==teamName,]
  })
}
```